# Why `ArrayList` is faster than `LinkedList` , while adding item at end of the list?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am not able to understand why `linkedlist` takes more time when element is added at the end of the list ,
 and why `arraylist` takes more time when element is added at the beginning of the list
`List<Integer> linkedlist = new LinkedList<Integer>();`
`List<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

```
    doTiming("ARRAYLIST",arraylist);//give any method name
    doTiming("LINKEDLIST",linkedlist);

}
//following method is here used to insert few record before checking their timing.
public static void doTiming(String type, List<Integer> list){
    for(int i=0;i<1E5;i++){
        list.add(i);
}
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

//addding item at end of list 
    for(int i=0;i<1E5;i++)
    {
        list.add(i);// after this loop , no loop further , and execute than arraylist is faster than linkedlist
    }


    //adding items at the beginning of the list 
/*  for(int i=0; i<1E5; i++)
    {
        list.add(0, i); //means i'm going to add the item at 0th index of list.
        //adding items at the beginning or middle of the list , arraylist takes lots of time compared to linkedlist


    }
    */
/*  for(int i=0; i<1E5; i++)
    {
        list.add(list.size()-99, i); //now arraylist faster , as we know arrylist is faster to add item at the end.

    }  */
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("time taken :"+(end-start)+"milli second for "+type);
```

Blockquote

Comment: You could answer this yourself the fun way; look at the src code.

Answer (score 4):

**ArrayList** is backed by an array that holds the data. When the array is full it will allocate a new, larger array and copy over all the data from the old to the new one. You are right, if you only add/remove at the end then using an `ArrayList` is the best, but if you add/remove at the beginning then the performance will suffer because you have to copy all the data one element to the right when adding a new element at the front.

**Vector** is just like the `ArrayList` but threadsafe.

**LinkedList** does not have a limit, for each new element it will just allocate a new node and let the `next` pointer in the tail point to this node which becomes the new tail.

**Adding at beginning of the list**
The `LinkedList` has a head-note which indicates where the list starts and each entry is pointing to the next one. When inserting at the beginning, the new entry will become the head node and its next-pointer points to the old head. This can be done in constant time O(1).

The `ArrayList` has to make space first by copying all its elements one entry to the right and then inserting the new elemnt at the leftmost position in the array. The cost of this is linear in the size of the list O(n).

**Inserting at the end**

The `LinkedList` usually keeps a pointer to the tail of the list (i.e. the last element). When adding a new element, the next-pointer of the old tail will point to the new element and the new element will become the new tail.

The `ArrayList` has to first check if there is space left in the array. If yes the element will be added in the next free field and the pointer pointing to the free field will be incremented. If not, then the list allocates a new array that is larger than the old one, copies all elements from the old array to the new one and then inserts the new value at the end.

It can be shown that both implementation have the same amortized costs for this operation. The reason why the `ArrayList` is faster in practise is that the `LinkedList` has to allocate a new object instead of just inserting an element to an array. But the actual reason why you should use an `ArrayList` when you are only inserting/removing at the end is because 1. it consumes less memory since an array is more efficient than having a lot of objects and 2. the data is alligned in memory so reading all of the list is much faster due to the linear memory read compared to the random memory access of the `LinkedList` and 3. the `ArrayList` allows an efficient random read

For (a lot) more details its best to look at the source code:

[ArrayList Implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java)

[Vector Implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/Vector.java)

[LinkedList Implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java)

Comment: Yes, I read the above thing, But my question is different. I want to say how data (element) is added in list in background (in Data Structure) , so I can get idea about their timing. (How `LinkedList` take more time in compare to `ArrayList` while adding data at the end of the list )

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find the difference by reading the javadocs for these. Read source code to see the implementation.

Also, take an input of large numbers and perform these operations with a different data structure. Use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to find the time for overall operations and analyze the performances. You will get a good idea, and will have some fun too.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but just a reminder to future readers: do NOT benchmark using currentTimeMillis, use System.nanoTime instead and take look at JMH.